# How to translate seconds to minutes & seconds in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, math, time

I have a Bash script that downloads files from a website through it's API, and I wanted to implement a thing (for a lack of better words) at the end that would display how long it took for the script to complete. With this code, I was able to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
SECONDS=0

# -- Code to Execute --

echo "Task complete"
echo "Script completed in $(echo "scale=2; $SECONDS / 60" | bc) minutes"
```

However, this would display the time the script took to execute in fractions of a minute:

```
Task complete
Script completed in 1.35 minutes
```

How would I be able to translate the amount of seconds the script took to complete into minutes and seconds? Like this:

```
Task complete
Script completed in 1 minute and 12 seconds
```

Comment: I would like it to just display a numerical value for the amount of time it took the script to complete in both minutes and seconds, like codeforester's answer has done. (Example, translate 72 seconds to 1 minute and 12 seconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash is good at simple integer math:

```
total_time=100
minutes=$((total_time / 60))
seconds=$((total_time % 60))
echo "Script completed in $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds"
# output -> Script completed in 1 minutes and 40 seconds
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the integer division and modulo operators in the shell:

```
echo "Script completed in $((SECONDS/60)) minutes and $((SECONDS%60)) seconds"
```

If you want to leave out the seconds and minutes parts if they're zero, it's a little more complicated:

```
if (( SECONDS/60 == 0 )); then
            echo "Script completed in $SECONDS seconds"
elif (( SECONDS%60 == 0 )); then
    echo "Script completed in $((SECONDS/60)) minutes"
else
    echo "Script completed in $((SECONDS/60)) minutes and $((SECONDS%60)) seconds"
fi
```

(It'll still say things like "1 minutes" rather than "1 minute"; you could fix that too if you wanted to make it even more complicated...)

Comment: Your answer would've worked as well, but since it is a bit out of the extent that I need it for, I went ahead and accepted codeforester's answer . Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward through `awk` within a single line:

`echo $(seconds) | awk '{printf "%d:%02d:%02d", $1/3600, ($1/60)%60, $1%60}'`